# Mapping values to a certain class

Tags: jquery

```
 $.each(data, function (i, val) {
                        if ($('input:text').hasClass(i)) {
                            $('.' + i).val(val);
                        }
```

It works, but im not a big fan of the `$('.' + i).val(val);`. Must be a smarter way than combining strings using jquery, right?

Comment: class names cannot start with a number.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov forgot to mention that `i` in this case is the key in a json object, so its a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build selectors via string concatenation isn't a big deal. However using two selectors when one will work is wasteful:

```
$.each(data, function(i, val) {
  $('INPUT.' + i).val(val); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We use similar to that to describe classes.  You could combine the two:

```
$("input:text ." + i).val(val);
```

Comment: Yea i know, what i want to get rid of is the combination (concatenation) of the strings in the selector. But i guess that might not be possible...